# What was attributed to Trump's narrower margin of victory in Texas compared to Romney?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, statistics, texas

Romney won Texas by 16 points in 2012. Trump won Texas by 9 points in 2016. Both candidates got more votes though Clinton got more of an increase.

Did Clinton come closer to winning it because of Hispanic turnout? Vote flipping? Or a combination of those?

There was a question that is kind of the opposite here: [Which party actually caused the 2016 presidential election swing?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56796/which-party-actually-caused-the-2016-presidential-election-swing)

Comment: Nitpick: "What was attributed to X?" means: what things happened after X which people said were caused by X? I.e. What things were believed to be caused by Trump getting a narrower margin than Romney? I suspect the answer is "not much". The reverse question is "What was X attributed to?" or "To what was X attributed?".

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question. If you would like to answer, post a real answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the official exit poll, as well as some post-election analyses of the state seem to indicate that - rather than Latino voters turning out to vote against Trump - he actually performed better with that demographic than Romney. FiveThirtyEight [argues](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/trump-probably-did-better-with-latino-voters-than-romney-did/):

> In the lead-up to the election, there was a lot of talk about how
> Latinos would turn out in record numbers to stop Donald Trump. But not
> only did Trump end up winning, exit polls also indicated that he won
> 29 percent of the Latino vote — better than Mitt Romney had done four
> years earlier. That has sparked a heated debate among pollsters and
> advocacy groups over whether the exit polls can be trusted.
>
> ...
>
> No one doubts that Clinton won handily among Latinos. But the scale of
> that victory matters. Latino leaders — most of whom supported Clinton
> — want to argue that their constituents punished Trump for his
> policies on immigration and other issues, more so than they did Mitt
> Romney in 2012. Trump wants to be able to claim as broad a mandate as
> possible. And in the longer term, Latinos are one of the
> fastest-growing segments of the electorate, and Democrats are counting
> on their support to retake the presidency in 2020. But if Trump, who
> said many Mexican immigrants are “rapists” and questioned the
> impartiality of a Mexican-American judge, basically equalled Romney’s
> performance among Latinos — Trump won 29 percent according to exit
> polls, and Romney won 27 percent — that suggests that Republicans
> might be able to make gains in the future, or at least prevent
> Democrats from winning over a larger share of that voting population.

While these exit polls have been [criticised as inaccurate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2016/12/02/donald-trump-did-not-win-34-of-latino-vote-in-texas-he-won-much-less/), the analysis [presented](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/weekly-standard/blue-texas-its-way-more-complicated-than-you-think) by David Byler, Chief Elections Analyst at the Washington Examiner, agrees, stating:

> A shift in the Hispanic vote might be part of the story, but there’s
> still some disagreement among experts on this issue. Exit polls,
> pre-election polling, county-level results and data from the
> Cooperative Congressional Election Studies all suggest that Trump
> performed roughly as well (or maybe better) than Mitt Romney with
> Hispanic/Latino voters nationally. And the Griffin-Teixeira-Halpin
> found little difference between Obama’s and Clinton’s margin with
> Hispanics in Texas specifically. In other words, there’s some evidence
> that Texas Hispanics (who, according to estimates by the New York
> Times’ Upshot, already voted more Republican than Hispanics in states
> like California in 2012) might not have shifted far to the left in
> 2016.

Instead, he presents a different explanation - the shift among college-educated whites in Texas. This demographic has been looked at by the [Pew Research Center](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2018/03/20/1-trends-in-party-affiliation-among-demographic-groups/), which found "the widest educational gap in partisan identification and leaning seen at any point in more than two decades of Pew Research Center surveys".

> These overall patterns in education and partisanship are particularly
> pronounced among white voters. While the GOP has held significant
> advantages over the Democratic Party among white college graduates
> without postgraduate experience over much of the past two decades,
> these voters are divided in their partisanship today.
>
> [image]

[Analysis from the Center for American Progress](https://www.americanprogress.org/issues/democracy/reports/2017/11/01/441926/voter-trends-in-2016/) suggests that this was a significant contributor in Texas:

> Finally, in Texas, we also found improvement for the Democrats among
> both white non-college-educated and college-educated voters. The
> Democrats’ deficit among Texas’s white non-college-educated voters
> fell from 60 points in 2012 to 55 points in 2016. But the shift toward
> Clinton among white college graduates in the state was much
> larger—from a 30-68 percent deficit in 2012 to 37-57 percent in 2016,
> a margin improvement of 18 points. The white college-educated
> improvement, again, was the big factor here, cutting Clinton’s deficit
> in the state by almost 5 points compared to a boost of less than 2
> points from the white non-college-educated shift in her favor. There
> was also a modest improvement in the Democrats’ margin among Latino
> voters, increasing from 33 points in 2012 to 37 points in 2016. But
> that helped Clinton to the tune of only half a percentage point.

So in conclusion, the increasing Latino population may have been a factor, but many post-election analyses suggest that a greater factor is the shift of white, college-educated voters away from the Republican party & towards the Democrats.