# What explains this swing of areas near Canada and in Appalachia in the 2016 US presidential election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

I've seen pictures of the 2016 presidential election. They seem to show this line that goes across basically the entire US Canada border, but is more pronounced starting in North Dakota. It makes a curve south down into Tennessee and a little bit into northern Alabama. Then it curves up into Pennsylvania Upstate New York and the parts of New England near Canada. Example:

[image]

Trump won the Electoral College largely because of the fact that this swing went through states such as Michigan Wisconsin Pennsylvania Iowa and Ohio as well as a few states that were not competitive at the time. However Clinton won the popular vote partly through swings in urban areas. We saw similar images of this in the 2008-2012 shift to a lesser degree.

What explains this belt of counties shifting towards the Republicans?

Comment: In other words what do they have in common? Yes third party votes may have been decisive statewide in Michigan Wisconsin and Pennsylvania, but these swings can't be explained by 3rd parties.

Comment: Nearly every question about elections (2016 or 2020) cause some people gone berserk and downvote before read. +1, I don't think that question is bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which party actually caused the 2016 presidential election swing?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56796/which-party-actually-caused-the-2016-presidential-election-swing)

Comment: I, too, upvoted; this is a good question. I also however voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: The deepest red areas are lightly populated areas in the north and midwest. I've lived in the Houston area for 35 years, but those deep red areas are where my roots lie. I have relatives in North Dakota, northern Minnesota, northern Michigan, and northern Maine. They feel ignored, left behind, and alienated. Politics dominated by large cities bothers them, a lot. They uniformly did not want Hillary Clinton as President in 2016. They weren't so uniformly against Joe Biden in 2020. That's limited personal experience and also apocryphal, so it's not an answer.

Comment: Not close voting since it doesn't explicitly answer this question, but Jared Smith's answer on this question explains it pretty well I think.  I live in that arc and it explains why I voted for Trump anyways:
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35851/why-arent-republicans-more-focused-on-mobilizing-a-movement-towards-dethroning

Comment: I'm voting to leave open.  While the link provided by @DavidHammen answers a related question, this question is about a specific region and it's reasons don't necessarily match with the whole country, as evidenced by David's third comment which I think is a much better and more likely accurate answer.

Comment: @David Hammen:  In 2020, it was a combination of people not being much against Biden, and being very much against Trump, who had (among other things) shown himself to be just another clueless urbanite.  See for instance his suggestions of raking forests in order to prevent forest fires.

Comment: This is different because this is asking what caused a swing in a different region.

Answer (score 5):

There is no one magic thing that caused 2016 to swing the way it did. There are a lot of smaller effects that added up to a Trump win.

- [Trump out campaigned Hilary](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2016-election/trump-out-campaigned-clinton-50-percent-key-battlegrounds-final-100-n683116), and had a massive presence in those states especially.
- Trump was anti-establishment, and Hilary was about the most establishment candidate possible. Anti-establishment was in vogue at the time.
- Hilary was an extremely unpopular candidate, in large part due to a fairly continuous anti-Clinton campaign since the 90s. [She got less support than Obama in key voter demographics for Democrats](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2016/12/hillary-clintons-surprising-vote-deficit/509174/).
- The [DNC emails revealed that the Democrat primary was essentially fixed and this alienated a huge number of Bernie supporters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Democratic_National_Committee_email_leak).
- The [deplorables comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basket_of_deplorables) insulted about 50% of voters directly, and it's extreme poor taste turned off some supporters as well. This was reminiscent of [Romney's similar comment about the 48% that don't pay income tax will never vote Republican](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2012/09/where-are-the-47-of-americans-who-pay-no-income-taxes/262499/). Straight up insulting half the country you are trying to govern is not a good move.
- Trump ran on an anti-globalist platform, this resonated in states where globalism has resulted in a significant loss in industry. The Democrat platform was less appealing.

Comment: Tired of non-sourced opinions, so added some links. Roll back if you disagree.

Comment: This is an answer to the [linked duplicate question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56796/which-party-actually-caused-the-2016-presidential-election-swing), but this question is asking about this one region specifically. Nothing in your answer addresses the region in the question. If you think that a general answer like this is appropriate to the question, then this question should be closed as a duplicate of that other question.